# How i can display background image on email teamplate Laravel

Tags: laravel, email, markdown, background-image

I want to display background-image as a background of a email teamplate on laravel, how i can do it ?

Answer (score 0):

It's just basic HTML/CSS stuff. Nothing to do with Laravel

Ex:

```
<body style="background: url('{{ asset('images/your-image.jpg') }}')">
```

for more useful CSS

```
 no-repeat center center fixed; -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -o-background-size: cover; background-size: cover;
```

Read more -> [HTML Background Images](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images_background.asp)

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Email Template</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table width="100%" height="100%" style="background: url('https://www.yourwebsite.com/path-to-your-image.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -o-background-size: cover; background-size: cover;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h1>Hello, World!</h1>
                <p>This is a simple email template with a background image.</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It does not work , i tried it before ask, in gmail background image doesn't appear.

Comment: for gmail `background` will not support. use table instead